# Creating a exponential function in python

Tags: python

I want to write a function that takes a single floating-point parameter x and
returns the value of the function e(to the power of x) . Using the Taylor series expansion
to compute the return value, using a loop that terminates when the partial sum SN+1 of Eq. (2) is equal to SN.

Dont know how to make to the power of so i'm putting in a link to the [Wikipedia article for the Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Comment: Could you tell us more about what part you are stuck on? Seems to me you just implement this function with a check for when a value is sufficiently close to the previous. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/c/3/a/c3a379aaf2b04999084373279ed2da10.png

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please put down your efforts so far into the post, so people could help you.

Answer (score 9):

Imho there is no need to implement what is already there.

```
import math

math.exp(x) # equivalent to e ^ x
```

but if you insist, there is the `pow` function also:

```
import math

math.pow(x, y) # equivalent to x ^ y
```

Comment: Which part of this implements the Taylor series?

Comment: the question was where to find the *power* function. Not how to implement the taylor series. At least thats how I understood the question.

Comment: There is a need to reinvent the wheel if doing so is your homework assignment...

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: There was no mention that the question was in a context of a homework. The tag `homework` was not added by the OP and *after* I answered the question. From the given information I assumed that the OP was indeed unnecessarily trying to *reinvent the wheel*.

Answer (score 9):

Constantinius has a good answer, but I thought I would add that the python shortcut for exponentiation is **.

E.g.

```
 >>>2**3
 8
```

Note however that e**x is handled differently than math.exp(x):

```
 >>>math.e**3
 20.085536923187664
 >>> math.exp(3)
 20.085536923187668
```

Comment: Is either of them (`math.e**x` vs `math.exp(x)`) more correct than the other? Why? Thanks!

Comment: I would assume math.exp is the better choice:

The pow() function (which is what ** is a shortcut for) converts both items to the same type as its first step, which means that math.e will be rounded to float(2.718281828459045) immediately. This seems like a lot of precision, but the rounding error will become more and more important with higher exponents. 

I don't know the internals, but I would guess that the math.exp algorithm produces the actual value of e^x and then converts that result into a float. 

So the difference is probably that one rounds before and the other rounds afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

the taylor series developed at 0 is:

f(x)  = exp(0) + exp(0)/1*x +  exp(0)/(1*2)*x^2 + exp(0)/(1*2*3)*x^3 + exp(0)/(1*2*3*4)*x^4 + ...

= 1 + x + 1/2*x^2 + 1/6*x^3 + 1/24*x^4 +...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The OP is clearly familiar with the Taylor series already; the question is about how to code it.